# Find field inside an array using $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a `invoice collection`, in which I want find the document with a specified book's id.

```
  db.invoice.find({"sold": {$elemMatch: {"book":{$elemMatch:{"_id":"574e68e5ac9fbac82489b689"}}}}})
```

I tried this but it didn't work

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575e9bf5576533313ac9d993"),
    "sold" : [
        {
            "book" : {
                "_id" : "574e68e5ac9fbac82489b689",
                "price" : 100,
            },
            "quantity" : 10,
            "total_price" : 1000
        }
    ],
    "date" : "13-06-2016"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need the [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) query operator here because you only specify only a single *query* condition.

```
db.invoice.find( { 'sold.book._id': '574e68e5ac9fbac82489b689' } )
```

This is mentioned in the documentation:

> If you specify only a single  condition in the $elemMatch expression, you do not need to use $elemMatch

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch

> The **$elemMatch** operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

```
mongo> db.invoice.find({"sold": {$elemMatch: {"book._id":"574e68e5ac9fbac82489b689"}}}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575e9bf5576533313ac9d993"),
    "sold" : [
        {
            "book" : {
                "_id" : "574e68e5ac9fbac82489b689",
                "price" : 100
            },
            "quantity" : 10,
            "total_price" : 1000
        }
    ],
    "date" : "13-06-2016"
}
```

Comment: I think the query is still using `$elemMatch` unnecessarily. Just `{'sold.book._id': '574e68e5ac9fbac82489b689'}` query will work fine.